# well ordered subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with infinite boundary points

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m searching (without any luck) for a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $A$ is well ordered (with the normal order of $\mathbb{R}$)
- $A$ has an infinite number of boundary points

**Definition:** Suppose $U$ is a well ordered set and $0$ it’s least element.

A point $x\in U$ is called boundary iff $x\neq 0$ and $(\forall u<x)(\exists v\in U)[u<v<x]$

I think if such a set exists it must be the infinite union of countable sets but I can’t find an example.

**Thank you in advance for your time and effort.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set 
$$ A = \left\{n - \frac 1m \biggm| n, m \in \mathbb N, n \ge 1, m\ge 2 \right\}$$
Then $A$ is well-ordered (each $A \cap [n-1, n)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$) and all $n\ge 1$ are boundary points.

Comment: Thank you, yep that seems to work. Do you need to incude $n$ in $A$? so that $A=\{n-\frac{1}{m}|n,m\in\mathbb{N},n\geq 1,m\geq 2\} \cup \{n|n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 1\}$

Comment: Yes, you should do that ...

Answer (score 2):

For this a little knowledge of ordinals is useful.

1. Every countable ordinal is embeddable into $\Bbb R$ (and in fact into $\Bbb Q$).
2. An ordinal has infinitely many "boundary points", as you define them, if and only if it is larger than $\omega^2$, which is the first limit ordinal which is the limit of limit ordinals itself.